# What is the difference between `e1` and `&e2` when used as the for-loop variable?

Tags: rust

The compiler says that `e1: &i32` and `e2: i32`. Having read the docs [for `slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) and [the book chapter on loops](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/loops.html), I'm still confused.

More generally, can a particular element in a slice be owned? It seems like in case 2, `e2` is owning an element, is it?

```
fn main() {
    let slice = &[1, 2, 3];
    for e1 in slice.iter() {
        println!("{}", e1); // case 1
    }

    for &e2 in slice.iter() {
        println!("{}", e2); // case 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used in a *destructuring pattern binding*, the ampersand `&` is used to dereference a value:

```
let a_number: i32 = 42;
let a_reference_to_a_number: &i32 = &a_number;

let another_reference = a_reference_to_a_number;
let &another_number = a_reference_to_a_number;

let () = another_reference; // expected type `&i32`
let () = another_number;    // expected type `i32`
```

This applies anywhere a pattern is accepted, such as in a `let` or `if let`, as a function argument, the for-loop variable, or a match arm.

---

While initially confusing to many people, this is actually the language being consistent with how enums and structs are pattern matched and thus *removed* from the inner variable binding:

```
let a_value: Option<&i32> = Some(&42);

if let Some(&val) = a_value {
    let () = val; // expected type `i32`
}
```

Note how `val` is no longer "wrapped" by the `Some`, just like it is no longer "wrapped" by the reference.

This behavior of `&` in patterns is why the `ref` keyword is needed. The `ref` keyword is used to unambiguously *introduce* a reference in a pattern match.

Comment: I see. Is the ownership transferred to `e2` (in my example)?

Comment: @qweruiop No more or less than if you had used `*e1` in the first loop. An `i32` implements `Copy`, so it will copy the bits. If it didn't implement `Copy`, you'd get the "cannot move out of borrowed context" error. The default is that you cannot take ownership of the value behind a reference because doing so would leave the referenced item in an unknown state.

Comment: Okay. I tried with a struct without `Copy`, I did get that borrow error. Is it equivalent to say: If a value has references, then its ownership can't be taken through its refs?

Comment: @qweruiop equivalent to which part? You can *never* transfer ownership through a reference. If you have a reference to something that implements `Copy`, then dereferencing it might go ahead and make that copy. If it implements `Clone`, you could call `clone` on the reference and get something you own. In either case, the original owner of the value that the reference is to still owns the value.

Comment: To "The default is that [...]". But I think I get it. Thanks.