# Why borrow an element on a for loop when the element is already a borrowed one

Tags: for-loop, rust

I am learning rust using the Rust book and also a video course by [Let's Get Rusty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX9HJsJUDxA&%20list=PLai5B987bZ9CoVR-QEIN9foz4QCJ0H2Y8) on youtube which goes through the book chapter by chapter and explains the book. But under this  [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) which talks about the slice type I dont understand this code snippet

```rust
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}

fn main() {}
```

As I can understand first `s.as_bytes()` returns a reference of an array of bytes. Now we iterate over the reference of the bytes using a for loop and since we want to use the indices we use enumerate which returns the index which is a type of `usize` and the element itself which is a reference to the byte(as indicated by the book). So my question did the book use `&item` on the for loop declaration while already the item is a reference to the byte?

When removing the `&` from the `item` the `item` will be a reference to the byte, but when using the `&` the type will change to `u8` (which is a byte). And that's what confused me I tried to recreate the scenario by doing this

```rust
let some_string = String::from("hello");
let &some_var = &some_string;
```

Which of course will result in an error.

I would absolutely love a thorough explanation.

Comment: Note that `as_bytes()` doesn't return an array, but a _slice_ reference. With a slice, you can only iterate over the references to the thing inside, because you don't own the slice. `&item` is a _pattern_, where `&` doesn't create a reference, it _destructures_ it. You can think of `&` in the pattern as being the _opposite_ of `&` in an expression. And that's not specific to `&`, patterns work like that everywhere. E.g. `if let Some(foo) = bar` doesn't create an option, it destructures it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197990) contains an excellent explanation to what's happening here.

Comment: I now understand how this works. I haven't read about patterns yet, but I will Thanks for the explanation and recommendation.